# Iterated multiplication of permutation matrices

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits, matrices, permutations, matrix-multiplication

> Given $m$ matrices of size $n\times n$ each of which is promised to be a permutation is it in $\mathit{quasiAC}^0$ or $\mathit{AC}^0$ to multiply the permutations where

1. $m=\mathit{poly}(n)$
2. $m=\mathit{poly}(\log n)$ which means $m=O(\log^k n)$ where $k\in\mathbb N_{>1}$
3. $m=O(\log n)$?

Given $\mathit{poly}(n)$ inputs it is clearly in $\mathit{AC}^0$ to test the promise every input matrix is a permutation.

On other hand general iterated matrix multiplication is is $\mathit{NC}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ben Rossman](https://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/%7Eigorcarb/complexity-meetings-files/Rossman-Talk.pptx) showed that any unbounded fan-in depth $d$ circuit for your problem has size at least $n^{\Omega(m^{1/2d})}$. Conversely, a simple recursive construction gives an unbounded fan-in depth $d$ formula of size $n^{O(m^{1/d})}$.

Comment: I trust that you can do the arithmetic on your own.

Comment: The bound stated is incorrect or else it separate NC1 and AC1. I think m is restricted.

Comment: Do you know the correct reference (I see R'08 R'14 etc but no right reference)? Are you certain $m$ is not bounded by $\log n$ or $\log\log n$ or anything?

Comment: I’m not sure it has been published yet. In the slides there are some limits on $d$.

Comment: Yes unlikely these tricks can prove lower bounds.

Comment: Why not? Rossman proved several tight lower bound and separations using these methods. They’re quite sophisticated.

Comment: Still these simple counting pigeonhole tricks cannot budge NC1 vs AC1 since DLOGTIMEuniformNC1=CH is not ruled out.